# Can long running query improves performance using AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-redshift

As we are a data warehouse team, we deals with millions of records in and out on daily basis. We have jobs running ever day, and loads on to SQL Server Flex clones from oracle DB through ETL loads. As we are dealing with huge amount of data and complex queries, query runs pretty longer and it goes to hours. So we are looking towards using AWS. We wanted to setup our own licensed Microsoft SQL server on EC2. But I was wondering, how this will improve performance of long running query. What would be the main reason that same query takes longer on our own servers and executes faster on AWS. Or did I misunderstood the concept?(just letting you know I am at a learning phase)

PS: We are still in a R&D phase. Any thoughts or opinion would be greatly appreciated regarding AWS for long running queries.

Comment: What kind of query is long running? why would it belong running?

Comment: theoretically it should perform same if change is only in terms of where it is hosted, so just by changing the environment query will not run faster but if you use SQL Sever as service then you will get better scaling options but you have to pay more for a poorly written query.

Comment: Check what the query is waiting on on your on-prem instance and compare it to what it's waiting on in EC2. Runtime wait statistics are available in actual query plans on recent versions of SQL server. If you're not on a recent version of SQL server, you'll have to back into it in other ways.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide more details on your question.
What is your query ? 
How big is the tables ?
What is the bottle neck ? CPU ? IO ? RAM ?
AWS is just infrastructure. 
It does makes your life easier because you can scale up or down your machine in a click of buttons.

Well, I guess you can crank up your machine to however big you want, but even so, nothing will solve a bad query and bad architecture.

Keep in mind, EC2 comes with 2 type of disk. EBS and Ephemeral.
EBS is SAN. Ephemeral is attached to the EC2 instance it self.
By far, Ephemeral will be much faster of course, but the downside is that when you shutdown your EC2 and start it up again, all of the data in that drive is wiped clean.

As for licensing (windows and SQL Server), it is baked into the EC2 instance pre baked AMI (Amazon Machine Image). 
I've never used my own license in EC2.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As I said we just get started and looking in this perspective. I don't have exact numbers for now. I don't want to give approximate. I will try to get all the details you have asked.

Answer (score 0):

With same DB, Same hardware configuration, query will perform similarly on AWS or on prim. You need to check whether you have configured DB / indexes etc optimally. Also, think of replicating data to some other database which is optimized for querying huge amount of data.